# Unrecognized error in boost library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I got this code from a book (Boost C++ Application Development Cookbook) and I tried running it, it compiled with g++ but when I try running it, it gives me this error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
  what():  unknown option ranges
Aborted (core dumped)"
It didn't compile with clang, 
I compiled with "g++ ex1.cxx -lboost_program_options" and "clang ex1.cxx -lboost_program_options"

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/errors.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace opt = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    opt::options_description desc("All options");
    // 'a' and 'o' are short option names for apples
    desc.add_options()("apple,a", opt::value<int>()->default_value(10),
        "apples that you have")
        ("oranges,o", opt::value<int>(), "oranges that you have")("name",
        opt::value<std::string>(), "your name")("help", "produce help message");
    opt::variables_map vm;
    opt::store(opt::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    opt::notify(vm);
    if(vm.count("help")){
        std::cout << desc << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    try{
        opt::store(opt::parse_config_file<char>("apples_oranges.cfg", desc), vm);
    }
    catch(const opt::reading_file& e){
        std::cout << "Failed to open 'apples_oranges.cfg': " << e.what();
    }
    opt::notify(vm);
    if(vm.count("name")){
        std::cout << "Hi, "<< vm["name"].as<std::string>() << "!\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Fruits count: "
        << vm["apples"].as<int>() + vm["oranges"].as<int>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind indenting the code? Can you tell where the exception is thrown?

Comment: I indented it, the try and catch is clear now

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is nicer to read. Can you say where the exception is thrown?

Comment: What's the contents of `apples_oranges.cfg`? Or is that not reached?

Comment: The code doesn't have a throw, just a try and catch and the error didn't give any line number

Comment: the content of apples_oranges.cfg is "oranges = 20"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo here

```
vm["apples"].as<int>();
```

should be

```
vm["apple"].as<int>();
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a6d23a6613116e2)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/errors.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace opt = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    opt::options_description desc("All options");
    // 'a' and 'o' are short option names for apples
    desc.add_options()
        ("apple,a",   opt ::value<int>()->default_value(10), "apples that you have")
        ("oranges,o", opt ::value<int>(),                    "oranges that you have")
        ("name",      opt ::value<std::string>(),            "your name")
        ("help", "produce help message");

    opt::variables_map vm;
    opt::store(opt::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

    opt::notify(vm);
    if(vm.count("help")){
        std::cout << desc << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    try{
        opt::store(opt::parse_config_file<char>("apples_oranges.cfg", desc), vm);
    }
    catch(const opt::reading_file& e){
        std::cout << "Failed to open 'apples_oranges.cfg': " << e.what();
    }
    opt::notify(vm);
    if(vm.count("name")){
        std::cout << "Hi, "<< vm["name"].as<std::string>() << "!\n";
    }
    int a_ = vm["apple"].as<int>();
    int o_ = vm["oranges"].as<int>();
    std::cout << "Fruits count: " << a_ + o_ << std::endl;
}
```